# PHP script to check for alter mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, alter, user-permissions

I am trying to install a Photo App (ZenPhoto) on my webserver and the installer complains:

```
Warning!
Your Database user must have Alter, Create, Delete, Drop, Index, Insert, Select and Update rights.

Grants found:

GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'xxx'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'xxx'
```

My hosts control panel displays me only following database user permissions:

```
Select Update Create Insert Delete Drop
```

So INDEX and ALTER are missing?
I could complete the install but would like to know if I should expect any problems?
Is there a PHP / mySQL function that I can use to check if I can ALTER the db?

Answer (score 0):

```
GRANT INDEX, ALTER ON `server`.`database` TO `username`@`username_server`;
```

But my guess is you do not have those rights.. Best thing to do is then just contact your host and ask for those rights on your user.